# PTC integrity CLI no commands are recognized

Tags: mks-integrity

I have PTC integrity installed on my PC, but I would like to use CLI commands.

Unforonutaly, no PTC command is recognized in my console. Probably I have to set up some system env variables?

Or do I need some extra software/server installed besides?

I tried the next commands so far:

```
man imabout
man "im about"
man "im"
```

> No manual entry for

```
im
si
```

> 'im' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

Answer (score 1):

when im is not recognized by your system, then

1) PTC is not running

or

2) your environmental variable is missing the entry:
**C:\Program Files\Integrity\Lifecyle Manager Client\bin**

Answer (score 0):

1. First, check if you are using the client network if yes then use the
   respective VPN with pulse secure or any VPN set-up with the
   respective client VPN.
2. Second, if its in local n/w or at server location use the below basic
   command

> mksapiviewer --iplocal --xml im connect --hostname=HOSTNAME --port=7001
> --user=ALM_USER --password=PASSWORD > Filename.txt

This will give you output in the text file and which is generated in the user folder or you can give manual file location.

If XML's exit code is coming "0" then it means the command run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when Tool path is not added into the PATH variable, please add the upto the Client_Install_Dir/bin directory.